# Timelineday and agendaDay buttons have the same label "Day"

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar and I have trouble to give the 2 view buttons I use in the header a unique name. Both Timelineday and agendaDay view give me the default value "Day" and that is confusing.

If I use buttonText property as mentioned here: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/buttonText/ to change the buttons, I can only rename both buttons at the same time and not just one.

Who knows the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To assign a custom name to a button you place your buttons on the header and then with that name you assign them with buttonText.

```
header: {
        left: "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay today prev,next",
        center: "title"
},
buttonText: {
        agendaWeek: "Custom Agenda Week Title"
}
```

Comment: @Vincent If the answer solves your problem you should consider [accepting it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to let others know the problem is solved.